# How do I save a coupon to Google Wallet

Tags: web, wallet, google-wallet

I have a page in my Web application where I generate coupons for my users (simple pictures with a logo and a discount code).
How do I go about implementing a feature where (after they click on a link in the browser, say) the coupon gets added to their Google Wallet?

I assume my web page should call into a Google API (somehow passing in the image of the coupon) but I can't find the API in question.
The examples I see are from an Android application perspective. My application is a web application (though run on an Android phone).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Wallet Rest API. See the documentation for [Offer pass type](https://developers.google.com/wallet/retail/offers/web#saving_to).